# Apply function to values and index of series

Tags: pandas

I'm finding myself applying a function to the values and the index of a TimeSeries. The way I do this is by building a DataFrame of the the values and and the index of the TimeSeries and then applying a function to the DataFrame.

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Set up some input time series
dates = pd.date_range('2012-04-01', periods=500,freq='MS')
ts = pd.Series(np.arange(500), index=dates)

# Build data frame of values and index
tmp = pd.concat([ts, ts.index.to_series()], join='outer', axis=1)

# Example function to apply
f = lambda x: x[0] / 4 if x[1].month % 3 == 1 else 0

# Apply function
out = tmp.apply(f, axis=1)
```

I have a sneaking suspicion that this is not the most elegant / efficient way to approach this but can't find anything in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/) to suggest a better route. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a more efficient solution

```
s = Series(np.arange(500), index=dates)
(s/4).where(s.index.month % 3 == 1, 0)
```

Comment: That doesn't work (although it looks like it should!). When I apply your solution I get `s` where `s.index.month % 3 == 1` and `s/4` where `s.index.month % 3 != 1`; I wanted `s/4` and `0` respectively

Comment: @Jeff This is wrong, the third argument to where is `inplace` so the `0` means `False` here and is actually the default.

Comment: ok I think is easy to enable though, let me think about it. you can also do as a chained loc (same idea)

Comment: Awesome. Nearly 40 times faster to boot! As an idea it is limited to if statement evaluations but that's a common enough use case to make this idiom worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it at least a little bit more elegant by using the DataFrame as follows

```
ts = pd.DataFrame({ "data": np.arange(500) }, index=dates)
f = lambda x: x["data"] / 4 if x.name.month % 3 == 1 else 0
ts.apply(f, axis=1)
```

You can access the index of a dataframe's element using the `name`-property.

Comment: I like the idea and is along the lines of what I was thinking about. The trouble is I can't make it work, if I apply your exact code (plus my def of dates) I get a Type Error: `TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'buffer' and 'int'", u'occurred at index 2012-04-01 00:00:00')`

Comment: If I debug inside the function that is `.apply`ed I seem to just have an array of values, representing a given row of data in `x`. I suspect things like the `.name` method only works outside of `.apply` as inside you're not really working with a DataFrame object any more

Comment: Sorry for that, it's fixed now (`df.data` returns the internal storage, if you name a column `"data"` you have to use `df["data"]`).

Comment: And you /are/ working on a `DataFrame` object inside of `apply` indeed.

Comment: Actually inside `apply` we seem to be working with a `Series` object, the name of which is the index of the `DataFrame` we're iterating through. This is why your name suggestion works for accessing the value of the index. It seems `apply` collapses a "dimension" of the initiating object so this is why working on a `TimeSeries` directly only left me with a value object and no way to access the value of the index. Not a perfect solution then but def better than where I was. Thanks again for all the help.